# Where is the best place to discuss downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I see some users indicating that they've received downvotes in the comments, and asking their downvoter to justify why they downvoted the question.  Is this acceptable for discussion? Should this occur in the comments, or somewhere else?

Comment: When such comments are flagged as no longer needed, they get deleted

Comment: Generally, it just generates drama to ask why someone downvoted.  Either the commentor is looking to argue with whoever downvoted, or won't accept the reasoning, and will complain when no one responds.  If someone wanted to comment, they would have when they downvoted.

Comment: Good question, enharmonic, +1. Unfortunately it would appear that the answer is _somewhere other than stack exchange_, which is a pity.

Answer (score 4):

The downvoter ought to feel absolutely no duty to reply to such a comment, although of course, the author of the question or answer is perfectly entitled to solicit a comment; politely.

In which case a single comment could be made by the downvoter, aimed at improving the question or answer. Perhaps further comments can be made following any edits.

Any further discussion ought to take place in chat, if at all.

Comment: I find that most requests for explanations are not made in good faith; they expect downvoters to justify them, and won't generally accept criticism in the first place.  It's an exercise in futility to respond to them.

Comment: Bathsheba: -1. I disagree. If I downvote, I feel I owe it to the poster to make some kind of (helpful polite) comment. It's disconcerting for a poster, especially a new poster, to receive a host of downvotes with no explanation, especially if their question is genuine. I would counter fbueckert's comment above by saying some downvotes are not made in good faith.

Comment: @JohnDuffield [Citation needed]

Comment: @fbueckert : see this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193862/what-constitutes-a-blackhole-firewall/193919?noredirect=1#comment967172_193919

Comment: @JohnDuffield That's not a citation.  That's you disagreeing with their decision.

Comment: @fbueckert : I didn't disagree at all. My link showed you psitae saying _"Would anyone like to explain why this answer has so many down votes?"_ Nobody answered. Google on [downvote to oblivion](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=w7qzW6T7AeqVgAaXnoY4&q=%22downvote+to+oblivion%22+site%3Astackexchange.com&oq=%22downvote+to+oblivion%22+site%3Astackexchange.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...13920.14439.0.14792.4.4.0.0.0.0.83.250.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.FbUKchjhV10).